AWS DMS shows records Mismatched records
I have a CDC DMS job and got a validation error mismatch record. It has a datatype mismatch so I knew that was the problem. After fixing the datatype it still did not get solved.
I tried matching the data type in source and target and restating the job again to fix the error, but it did not work.


You are leaving some critical parts to help solve the problem. Can you post the actually validation error and the columns and datatypes in question?

the column name is DATA and the datatype is text in both source and destination. when I compare both the table column data, I can see that the destination is not loading fully and is chipping almost 200 lines. The error says data mismatch because of that

I do not know what the validation issue is, however, if you are running in "limited LOB mode" your blob field could be subject to truncation at a configurable size. However, I do not know if that would trigger a mismatch during validation. -->https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.LOBSupport.html
